# Is using an API for login validation safe

Tags: c#, security, authentication

Ok, so i am creating a c# win forms program that has a login form that uses a basic api i host on my website for the login validation (served over HTTPS).

So for example here is some code

```
    WebClient wb = new WebClient();
    wb.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.33 Safari/537.36");
    String response = wb.DownloadString("https://www.example.com?username="+userName+"&password="+password);
    if(response == "1")
    {
        //logged in
    }
```

I was just woundering if it is secure to use an API for login validation like i did in my example.. Thanks for reading

Comment: What is the login securing? If it's just access to the winforms application, then no; that's not secure. Someone could intercept the request by changing their hosts file, using a proxy or whatever and have it return whatever result they want.

Answer (score 1):

**If** the API owns performing tasks for an authenticated user, this is fine.

That is to say that the windows form application is a lightweight client only, but all actions that require authentication and certain authorisation levels are owned by the API. Meaning that without a valid token or similar the API simply rejects the attempt.

Please don't authenticate using query string parameters though, you should always authenticate with an API securely over HTTPS and ensure that sensitive information is hidden away in the message body of a post.

The query string parameters will be encrypted and non visible during transit but it's just bad practice to place sensitive information there. Especially passwords. Don't forget, when they hit the server on the other end, the URL is in plaintext so that it can be handled by the relevant web server pipeline such as IIS. Meaning that they will be visible in the logs and other areas too.